# Defining package conflict resolving precedence in ANY java build manager (maven, gradle, sbt etc.)

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, sbt

I'm building a project on Cloudera Hive and Spark 5.10.2.

When I try to use a Thrift client to send out a request, I got the following error:

```
ERROR HiveConnection: Error opening session
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{use:database=default})
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:143)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:583)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:192)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Digging into the dependency tree of my project I discover that the problem is caused by a dirty monkey patch in Cloudera's hive-exec, in which the following dependency is defined:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
  <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
  <version>${libthrift.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But also thrift code generation is used to generate another set of implementation of libthrift, it ends up with both implementations exists in the classpath, and one of them got loaded randomly.

I'm looking for a plugin for maven, gradle or sbt to always load the generated version of libthrift when both exists, and only load the static version if there is no other choice, that is, to declare packages in hive-exec to have higher precedence over packages in libthrift. Is it possible to do so in the entire Java ecosystem?

Thanks a lot for any thought!

Comment: What do you mean "when both exist"? I understood that you found out that both exist.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [maven dependency exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)? 
Some helpful stuff when dealing with dependencies: `mvn help:effective-pom` and `mvn dependency:tree`.